# Problem with Router Push and Toast Notifications in Laravel and VUE 3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, toast, primevue

I have a problem and it is that when switching between components with router.push the Toast notification is not shown. I have the user edit view and what I want to do is redirect to the user's profile once it has been edited and immediately show the toast notification.

Roughly, I have the following:

**Routes.js**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

//Modules
import DashboardIndex from './components/modules/dashboard';
//Users
import UsersIndex from './components/modules/users';
import UsersCreate from './components/modules/users/create';
import UsersEdit from './components/modules/users/edit';
import UsersView from './components/modules/users/view';


export default new createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        { path: '/', name: 'dashboard.index', component: DashboardIndex },
        { path: '/users',  name: 'users.index', component: UsersIndex},
        { path: '/user/create',  name: 'user.create', component: UsersCreate},
        { path: '/user/edit/:id',  name: 'user.edit',  props: true, component: UsersEdit},
        { path: '/user/:id',  name: 'user.view',  props: true, component: UsersView},
    

    ]
})
```

**Composable/users.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import { useToast } from 'primevue/usetoast';

export default function useUsers() {

    const users = ref([])
    const user = ref([])
    const errors = ref([])
    const router = useRouter()
    const toast = useToast()
    /**
     * 
     * All Users
     * 
     */
    const getUsers = async () => {
       const response = await axios.get('/admin/users')
       users.value = response.data
    }
    /**
     * 
     * Create User
     * 
     */
    const storeUser = async (data) => {
        try {
            let response = await axios.post('/admin/user', data)
            await router.push({ name: 'user.view',  params: { id: response.data.id } })
        } catch (e) {
            if (e.response.status === 422) {
                errors.value = e.response.data.errors    
            }
        }
 
    }
    /**
     * 
     * Create User
     * 
     */
     const updateUser = async (id) => {
        try {
            //this.showToast = true;
            let response = await axios.put(`/admin/user/${id}`, user.value)
            router.push({ name: 'user.view',  params: { id: response.data.id } })
            toast.add({severity:'success', summary: 'Éxito', detail: 'El Usuario ha sido modificado', life: 3000})
        } catch (e) {
            if (e.response.status === 422) {
                errors.value = e.response.data.errors    
            }
        }

    }
     /**
     * 
     * View User
     * 
     */
    const showUser = async (id) => {
        let response = await axios.get(`/admin/user/${id}`)
        user.value = response.data

    }
 
    /**
     * 
     * Delete User
     * 
     */
    const destroyUser = async (id) => {
        await axios.delete(`/admin/user/${id}`)
    }
     

    return {errors, users, user, getUsers, storeUser, updateUser, showUser, destroyUser}

}
```

**View.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <Toast position="bottom-right"/>
USER PROFILE
                </div>
</template>
<script>
    import useUsers from '../../../composables/users'
    import { onMounted } from 'vue';

    export default {
        props: {
            id: { required: true }
        },
     
        setup(props) {

            const { user, showUser } = useUsers();

            const showUserMounted =  async () => {
                await showUser(props.id)
            }
            onMounted(showUserMounted)
           
            return { user }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

**Important fact, I'm using Prime VUE.**

And additionally I comment that, when I move to **toast.add({severity:'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'The User has been modified', life: 3000})** inside showUser it is shown well the toast message.

I think what I need is a flag that changes the value in the updateUser method (for example showToast = true) and from the showUser method verify if it is true, if so, execute the toast.add, but I don't know how to do this last.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you already somehow solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use pinia for store alert and you have access to alerts accross the app:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { useToast } from "primevue/usetoast";

export const useAlertStore = defineStore({
    id: "alert",
    state: () => ({
        toast: useToast(),
    }),
    actions: {
        success(title, message) {
            this.toast.add({
                severity: "success",
                summary: title,
                detail: message,
                life: 3000,
            });
        },
        info(title, message) {
            this.toast.add({
                severity: "info",
                summary: title,
                detail: message,
                life: 3000,
            });
        },
        warn(title, message) {
            this.toast.add({
                severity: "warn",
                summary: title,
                detail: message,
                life: 3000,
            });
        },
        error(title, message) {
            this.toast.add({
                severity: "error",
                summary: title,
                detail: message,
                life: 3000,
            });
        },
    },
});
```

then for example my login function:

```
const alert = useAlertStore();

async function login() {
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    await authStore.login(formData.email, formData.password);
    alert.success(
        t("alerts.loginTitle"),
        t("alerts.user") + `${authStore.user.name} ` + t("alerts.loginMessage")
    );
}
```

and for the end add Toast component to your App.vue file:

```
<template>
    <Toast />
    <router-view />
</template>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue with my Vue3 app written with Nuxt framework. Here is my solution with some additional comments to clarify problem and final solution.

using:

1. https://nuxt.com/modules/pinia
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-toastify

**store/toast.ts**

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useToastStore = defineStore('toast', () => {
  
  const toastMessage = ref<string | undefined>(undefined)
  const toastType = ref<string | undefined>(undefined)
  const toastDate = ref<Date | undefined>(undefined)

  const alert = (message: string, type: string = 'success') => {
    toastMessage.value = message
    toastType.value = type,
    toastDate.value = new Date()
  }

  return {
    alert,
    toastMessage,
    toastType,
    toastDate
  }
})
```

**components/Toast.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { toast } from 'vue3-toastify'
  import { useToastStore } from '~/store/toast'
  
  const toastStore = useToastStore()
  const { toastMessage, toastType, toastDate } = storeToRefs(toastStore)

  const showToast = (() => {
    if (toastMessage.value && toastType.value) {
      switch (toastType.value) {
        case 'error':
          toast.error(toastMessage.value)
          break
        case 'info':
          toast.info(toastMessage.value)
          break
        case 'warning':
          toast.warning(toastMessage.value)
          break
        default: 
          toast.success(toastMessage.value)
      }
    }
  })

  watch(() => toastDate.value, (newDate, oldDate) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      showToast()
    }, 100)
  })
</script>

<template></template>
```

**app.vue (or any other 'main' app or layout file)**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Toast />
    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

So As you can see  component is placed in main app file "outside" the `NuxtLayout` and `NuxtPage` components which are responsible for layout and page transitions and in general routing. (In "raw" vue.js app best place to put Toast component would be just next to `<router-view />`

Store is simple. It has only three values and one method, which we will use to set those variables on call `alert`. `toastDate` is important. We will use it to watch changes and run toast message.

Toast component. Quite simple too :). In `watch` I have set toastDate.value to watch and execute showToast() each time toastDate has changed. Small workaround here is to add small timeout before run `showToast()`. That's because vue.js have to change route and address in browser and call toast after change it. 100ms is more than enough for this and also it is "invisible" delay for the user.
So each time toastDate is updated w are calling `showToast()` after 100ms.

**How to use it?**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useToastStore } from '~/store/toast'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

const { alert } = useToastStore()
const router = useRouter()

...
router.push('/companies/')
alert(message)

</script>

And this is how it works: [https://youtu.be/6jrtZKt9EFI][1]


  [1]: https://youtu.be/6jrtZKt9EFI
```